# MySQL Fabric works with MyIsam tables?

Tags: mysql, innodb, high-availability, myisam

Well I'm using tables MyIsam that I can't modify and I would like to use MySQL Fabric.. is this possible? Because I have not seen anywhere if this possible.

Comment: MySQL Fabric works with GTID replication, which is independent of storage engine. I know of no reason why it wouldn't work with MyISAM.

Comment: I don't know why you say you can't modify your storage engine, but I guess it would result in some downtime? Also not a good reason—you can set up a replication slave and convert tables on the slave.

Comment: MySQL Fabric is a solution for HA clusters, but using MyISAM works counter to this goal. It's like building a skyscraper using excellent architecture, but using papier-mâché for the supports.

Comment: I can't to take advantage of the full-text indexes, emmm maybe the question is not well formulated, maybe MySQL Fabric just work with innodb, and I can't use it.

Comment: Well, MySQL Fabric requires GTID replication and MySQL 5.6. If you use MySQL 5.6, you can use fulltext indexes in InnoDB too. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html

Comment: Two strikes against your site -- Fabric is dead; MyISAM is dying.

Comment: Fabric is like building a skyscraper with only one elevator.  If the "fabric node" goes down, _all_ clients will soon be unable to connect to _any_ MySQL node.